# bind socket to network interface

Tags: c, linux, sockets

How can I bind a socket to a particular network interface? I tried using `setsockopt` on server side, but the clients can still access the service through both eth0 and lo interfaces.

I can achieve this by setting the particular IP address using  `serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr`.

But I suspect that we can bind to an interface using only `setsockopt` (without mentioning the IP address).

Answer (score 45):

You can bind to a specific interface by setting `SO_BINDTODEVICE` socket option.

```
struct ifreq ifr;

memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "eth0");
if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0) {
    ... error handling ...
}
```

**Warning**: *You have to be root or have the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability in order to use this option.*

The second method is that you can resolv IP address tied to an interface with [getifaddrs()](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/3/getifaddrs.htm).

Follow the latter link for a comprehensive example.

Comment: I have a new question, so does it matter eth0 and eth1 have same IP address using your method?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it should say "You have to be root *OR* have the CAP_NET_RAW capability", you don't need both.

Comment: Hi https://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt does not list SO_BINDTODEVICE is it no longer supported?

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can do it is as you mention -

> by setting the particular IP address using `serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr`

You can't do it without knowing the address to bind to.

You can use `ioctl`s to determine the current IP address if you need, though there may be a cleverer way to do this these days - I've not done much in modern Linux distros lately.

Comment: Thnks joe. can i know the usage of setsockopt with SO_BINDTODEVICE?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone will find it useful, so I am sharing the solution that worked for me (Linux, C++):

```
uint32_t interfaceIndex = if_nametoindex(interfaceName);
```

Where "interfaceName" is the name of the interface we want to bind to, e.g. "eth0" (see: https://linux.die.net/man/3/if_nametoindex).
Now we can specify this interface in the socket address structure via "sin6_scope_id" (in case we use IPv6):

```
struct sockaddr_in6 socketAddress;
socketAddress.sin6_scope_id = interfaceIndex;
```

Now we can bind the socket to the interface via "bind" as usual.