# Get IP address from socket descriptor?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, ip

I've opened a TCP socket server (I've omitted a few stuff, it is taken from [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html#simpleserver)

```
sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
            p->ai_protocol))
```

Is it possible to get the IP address of the server from sockfd? If not where should I look?

EDIT: I want to know the address of the server (this is before any client connects).

Comment: The I.P. address of which end? Yourself, or the place you've connected to? Or both?!

Comment: This socket isn't connected, so there's no address to get. After `accept`, `getsockname` will help.

Comment: `accept()` itself (optioally) returns the address of the peer that connected (see `man accept`).

Comment: The value return by a successful call to `socket()` isn't connected to any client nor bound to any interface, so there is no client side ip address nor a server side ip address that could be determined form anywhere.

Comment: The IP address is ```p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen``` immediately after the ```for()``` loop, if ```p``` is not ```NULL```.  This is simply because that's what the code ```bind```s the socket to.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to know who's at the other end of your socket you can use [getpeername](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpeername) in Linux. [getsockname](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getsockname) will tell you who you are. You decide what address you want your server to sit on initially though, at [bind](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bind) time.

You may also find this SO question useful: [bind socket to network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478167/bind-socket-to-network-interface)

And the book "Unix Network Programming, vol 1", by W. Richard Stevens.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the socket to get the server's address before a client connects, because it isn't known.

In principle, a host may have multiple IPs. The IP used for a connection to a server is the one belonging to the interface, through which the connection arrived. Until a connection arrives, it isn't known.
Even if you have only one IP, connections may arrive from within the machine, in which case the address would be `127.0.0.1`.

So the listening socket has no information about the IP.
You'll need to find what interfaces the machine has, and what's their IPs.

Comment: This is only partially, namely in the special case where `bind()` was called using `INADDR_ANY`. See the correct answer given by *Davide Berra*.

Comment: @alk, I assume that if he called `bind()` with a specific address, he wouldn't have asked what address it was.

Answer (score 1):

The address of the server is up to you.

Depends on which parameters are passed to the `bind()` function.

You can specify a `single ip` or bind your socket to every address of your host.

Look at the [Bind man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind)

Answer (score 0):

The address of the server is the one that was passed to the successfull call to `bind()` (as shown in the source you linked).