# Getting ip address from a socket fd (not duplicate)

Tags: c, sockets, trace, system-calls

I am attaching my process (with root privileges) to a browser process to intercepts its system calls using ptrace. To decode the parameters of the `connect()` system call i got the `sockfd`. But i have been trying from days to get the `ip address` of the other end of that socket but with no success.

i came accross these 2 questions while looking around

1)[Get IP address from socket descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711392/get-ip-address-from-socket-descriptor)

2)[Getting IP address, port and connection type from a socket fd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133564/getting-ip-address-port-and-connection-type-from-a-socket-fd)

I followed the suggestion of the 1st question, but somehow it was giving error. something `error: ‘struct sockaddr_in’ has no member named ‘sa_data’`. I digged deeper into the internet and got another hint, which i used to write this code

```
temp = getpeername(regs.rdi, (struct sockaddr *)&ip_addr_struct, &ip_addr_structlen);
struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&ip_addr_struct;
int port = ntohs(s->sin_port);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ip_addr, 1024);
printf("%d-%s\n", port, ip_addr);
```

here `regs.rdi` is the `sockfd`. But even with this code everytime i get `0-0.0.0.0`
 as output. please help anyone. Is there any other way to get the ip addrres or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Try getaddrinfo(). http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo

in_addr should be the field you should try to access using the sockaddr_in variable/pointer. Use pton() or ntop() to convert its format. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx63b042.aspx

Comment: @a4anurag: i am accessing `sin_addr` using sockaddr_in pointer, that is `s`. i didnt quite understand what `pton()` or `ntop()` would do. please explain a little more

Comment: @a4anurag: `getaddrinfo()` is for dns name resolution..

Comment: I believe `getnameinfo`, with `NI_NUMERICHOST`, is what you want.

Comment: @R..: can you plz give me an example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is to get the IP address of the connecting client, use this :)

```
struct sockaddr_in their_addr;

if ((*cli_fd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,&sin_size)) == -1)
{
    close (*cli_fd);
    return -1;
}

This is the client ip address ==> inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr)
```