# How to get a list of active network interfaces in C?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, networking

How to get the list of active interface in a system using C? what API or library i need to use? and Can i choose a particular interface to send data in socket programming? if yes then please give an example.

Comment: You can choose a specific interface by [binding](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bind.html) it to that interfaces address.

Comment: What operating system? (The answer here is more platform-specific than "unix")

Answer (score 1):

If on Linux you might like to take look at:

```
int getifaddrs(struct ifaddrs **ifap);
```

> The  [**getifaddrs()**](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=getifaddrs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en)  function  creates a linked list of structures describing the network interfaces of the local system, and stores the address of the first item of the list in *ifap.

Comment: but how to choose a particular interface to send data.(i.e. eth0/wlan0 etc.)

Comment: @prashant: Send to the interface's address or to an address routed via the interface.

Comment: can this "getifaddrs()" function able to detect interfaces for 3G/4G_LTE modem? it will be great if you can provide an example with output for the same. thanks!

Comment: @prashant: My answer links to a page containing an example on how to use `getifaddrs()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can show all the active network interfaces with [`ioctl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) and its different flags. You can find an exemple [here](http://www.adamrisi.com/?p=84).

You will be able to bind your socket to a specific interface, with [`setsockopt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt). An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478167/bind-socket-to-network-interface).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, use `GetAdaptersInfo()` and/or `GetAdaptersAddresses()`.

On most POSIX-compatible systems, you can use `getifaddrs()`.