# How do I get a list of available wifi-connections?

Tags: c, linux, wifi

Is there any way to get a list of available wifi-connections?

I want to write a simple program that lists the available wifi-connections and lets the user select a network to connect to.

Comment: Take a look at `iwlist` source code and specifically on its `scan` option implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of available wireless networks on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/400240/608639) Also see [Find available network interfaces in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8434918/608639), [How to get a list of active network interfaces in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18146236/608639) and [Determine if a network interface is wireless or wired](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12566911/608639).